# How to repeat univariate regression and extract P values?

Tags: r, regression, lapply, repeat

I am using `lapply` to perform several `glm` regressions on one dependent variable by one independent variable at a time. but I'm not sure how to extract the P values at a time.

There are 200 features in my dataset, but the code below only gave me the P value of feature#1. How can I get a matrix of all P values of the 200 features?

```r
valName<- as.data.frame(colnames(repeatData))
featureName<-valName[3,]
lapply(featureName,
       function(var) {       
         formula    <- as.formula(paste("outcome ~", var))
         fit.logist <- glm(formula, data = repeatData, family = binomial)
         summary(fit.logist)
         Pvalue<-coef(summary(fit.logist))[,'Pr(>|z|)'] 
       })
```

Comment: you can return the Pvalue at the end

Comment: Do you mean put Pvalue statement after })?  I tried this and got an error: "Error in summary(fit.logist) : object 'fit.logist' not found"

Comment: Not after. Before.
As in `lapply(featureName,......... Pvalue<-coef(summary(fit.logist))[,'Pr(>|z|)']    Pvalue`

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it. Still only got the first feature's P value.                               [[1]]
 (Intercept)          Sex 
0.0003512693 0.0002784681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I
I simplified your code a little bit; (1) used `reformulate()` (not really different, just prettier) (2) returned only the p-value for the focal variable (not the intercept p-value).  (If you leave out the 2, you'll get a 2-row matrix with intercept and focal-variable p-values.)

My example uses the built-in `mtcars` data set, with an added (fake) binomial response.

```r
repeatData <- data.frame(outcome=rbinom(nrow(mtcars), size=1, prob=0.5), mtcars)
ff <-   function(var) {       
         formula    <- reformulate(var, response="outcome")
         fit.logist <- glm(formula, data = repeatData, family = binomial)
         coef(summary(fit.logist))[2, 'Pr(>|z|)'] 
       }
## skip first column (response variable).
sapply(names(repeatData)[-1], ff)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!    I tried the code you kindly provided, it works pretty good with the mtcars data. But when I tried my data, it gave me another error: "Error in coef(summary(fit.logist))[2, "Pr(>|z|)"] : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Here’s the structure of my data. It looks pretty the same as mtcars data, I just cannot figure out what’s going wrong... 

Outcome  Sex F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F1
        0          1    2   2   1   1    2    2   1   1   2    2   1
        1           1    1   1    0  0    0    1   1   0  0    2   2

Comment: If it's not working you have to try to figure out how to give us a [mcve].  A debugging tip: put a `cat(var,"\n")` in as the first line of `ff` so you can identify which element is giving you trouble - then step through `ff` one command at a time to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I appreciated your help. Your code worked pretty well with the build-in dataset and  newly created test dataset. I'm still struggling with my dataset, but I'm more than happy to accept your answer.